# Empty/blank drop down, android custom search suggestion

Tags: android, database, widget, search-suggestion

I have a simple search widget and I have a hard time implementing the custom search suggestion function into my app.

The Google Api documentation on "[Building a suggestion table](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/search/adding-custom-suggestions.html)" is really poorly documented. So far I have managed to get my "SearchContentProvider" working, which returns suggestions, but as I type in the drop down  I get only "blank" fields and no text.

Could someone suggest me how to build the suggestion table? Where should I implement the "SUGGEST_COLUMN_TEXT_1" in order to format and get my suggestions right?

[image]

SearchContentProvider.java:

```
package com.exploreca.tourfinder;

import android.content.ContentProvider;
import android.content.ContentValues;

import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper;

import android.net.Uri;
import android.util.Log;

public class SearchContentProvider extends ContentProvider {

    SQLiteOpenHelper dbhelper;
    SQLiteDatabase database;        
    Cursor cursor; 
    private String LOGTAG;


    @Override
    public int delete(Uri arg0, String arg1, String[] arg2) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public String getType(Uri arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public Uri insert(Uri arg0, ContentValues arg1) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreate() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public Cursor query(Uri uri, String[] projection, String selection, 
              String[] selectionArgs, String sortOrder) { 

        //instantieting the datasouce
        dbhelper = new ToursDBOpenHelper(getContext());
        database = dbhelper.getReadableDatabase();
        Log.i(LOGTAG, "Selection Args: " + selectionArgs[0] + "\n " + "selection is: " + selection);        

        cursor = database.query(ToursDBOpenHelper.TABLE_TOURS, null, 
                selection, selectionArgs, null, null, null);

        Log.i(LOGTAG, "Returned" + cursor.getCount() + "rows");

        if (cursor.getCount() > 0){
            while(cursor.moveToNext()){         

                cursor.getColumnIndex(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(ToursDBOpenHelper.COLUMN_CITY)));
                Log.i(LOGTAG, "Cursor is" + cursor);
            }           
        } 
            return cursor;      
    }


    @Override
    public int update(Uri arg0, ContentValues arg1, String arg2, String[] arg3) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return 0;
    }

}
```

Comment: it is the column of returned suggestion Cursor

Answer (score 3):

If you still looking for a solution, you need to use SearchManager.SUGGEST_COLUMN_TEXT_1 instead of SUGGEST_COLUMN_TEXT_1, as [said in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6889285/search-suggestion-results-displayed-as-blank-no-text#answer-8270626).

Answer (score 0):

I have figured it out. Even if I have added the "SUGGEST_COLUMN_TEXT_1" as a new column to my table, it  remained empty, no matter what I had put in it.

So I have removed it form the database table and added it to my ContentProvider in the form of a HashMap, which consists of a set of key and value pairs. In the HashMap each key is mapped to a single value.

I have spend a few days figuring this out, hope to help others with the working code:

```
...

    @Override
    public Cursor query(Uri uri, String[] projection, String selection, 
                  String[] selectionArgs, String sortOrder) { 

                SQLiteQueryBuilder builder = new SQLiteQueryBuilder();
                builder.setTables(ToursDBOpenHelper.TABLE_TOURS);

                HashMap<String, String> columnMap = new HashMap<String, String>();
                columnMap.put(BaseColumns._ID, ToursDBOpenHelper.COLUMN_ID + " AS " + BaseColumns._ID);
                columnMap.put(SearchManager.SUGGEST_COLUMN_TEXT_1, ToursDBOpenHelper.COLUMN_TITLE + " AS " + SearchManager.SUGGEST_COLUMN_TEXT_1);
                columnMap.put(SearchManager.SUGGEST_COLUMN_INTENT_DATA, ToursDBOpenHelper.COLUMN_ID + " AS " + SearchManager.SUGGEST_COLUMN_INTENT_DATA);
                builder.setProjectionMap(columnMap);

                dbhelper = new ToursDBOpenHelper(getContext());
                //database = dbhelper.getReadableDatabase();

                SQLiteDatabase db = dbhelper.getWritableDatabase();
                cursor = builder.query(db, projection, selection, selectionArgs, null, null, sortOrder, null);

                return cursor;
        }

...
```